# What does the 'native buffer' mean in JVM?

Tags: jvm, websphere

I've got the below error from WebSphere Application Server's SystemOut.log file:

```
[5/11/12 8:13:46:291 GMT+08:00] 000063c0 WebApp        E   [Servlet Error]-[ICMResourceManager]: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to allocate 79683 bytes for native buffer
at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:290)
at com.ibm.mm.icmrm.storage.RMOutputStream.write(RMOutputStream.java:65)
at com.ibm.mm.icmrm.storage.RMDataTransfer.copyData(RMDataTransfer.java:150)
at com.ibm.mm.icmrm.storage.filesystem.FileSystem.store(FileSystem.java:104)
```

It seems the native OOM issue. I have a question here, is it the '**native buffer**' here same with '**direct byte buffer**'? Can I try to enlarge 'native buffer' size by reset property **XX:MaxDirectMemorySize**? BTW, what's the default value for it? 
Or can I set this property **-Dcom.ibm.nio.DirectByteBuffer.AggressiveMemoryManagement=true** to make native memory space dynamic?

WAS platform information:

```
WebSphere Platform 6.1 [ND 6.1.0.27 cf270937.16]  running with process name cmrmCell01\cmrmNode01\icmrm1 and process id 1802306
Detailed IFix information: Please use the versionInfo command to view this information
Host Operating System is AIX, version 5.3
Java version = 1.5.0, Java Compiler = j9jit23, Java VM name = IBM J9 VM
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't much of an answer, but see if this article, [Understanding how the JVM uses native memory on AIX](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-nativememory-aix/), has anything useful.

Comment: Helpful link; but it would be much more helpful if you quoted references from the link that help answer the question. See [how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).

Comment: @DanCruz Yes, I'm aware of that. But since I'm not able to do that at the moment, and especially since there are no other answers, I figured the requester would rather have the link without context than not have it at all.

Comment: it's good article, but i still can't get answer from that. Really badddddddd!